# Can't find /sys/class/net/vEth0/sock_en and /sys/class/net/vEth0/sock_fd

Tags: c, dpdk

When I read the [DPDK document](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/virtio.html), I got a problem that I can't get the descriptor of a NIC.

I want use virtio with kni vhost back end, but I can't find the file `/sys/class/net/vEth0/sock_en` and `/sys/class/net/vEth0/sock_fd`.

```
[root]# cd vEth0/
[root]# ls
addr_assign_type  addr_len   carrier  dev_port  duplex    flags    ifindex
link_mode  operstate     power   speed       subsystem     type
address broadcast  dev_id   dormant   features  ifalias  iflink   mtu
phys_port_id  queues  statistics  tx_queue_len  uevent`
```

I am using CentOS6.5 with kernel 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64.

Comment: Its likely you do not have the necessary device drivers installed.

Comment: @t0mm13b Unfortunately, I don't know what driver I should install, it's really make me upset. I spent so much time on this problem.

Comment: are building DPDk with static or sahred library mode? Can you also share DPDK version and arguments to run for sample application?